# Rspec validate uniqueness with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this in my Line model

```
validates :home_team, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:visiting_team, :event_datetime],
:message => "** DOUBLE EVENT **" }
```

I have this in my spec

```
describe Line do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime) }
```

I get this error...

Failures:

```
1) Line 
 Failure/Error: 

it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime) }
   Did not expect errors to include "has already been taken" when home_team is set to "arbitrary_string", got error: 
# ./spec/models/line_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 49):

I think you need to do this make it pass

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime).with_message("** DOUBLE EVENT **") }
```

The default error message of uniqueness is “has already been taken”.

Comment: Hi Roy :) Now I get.... I think I will have to try new approach.

1) Line 
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime).with_message("** DOUBLE EVENT **") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `change' for 1:Fixnum
     # ./spec/models/line_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: That worked for me too, but what if you want to validate uniqueness `unless: -> { home_team.nil? }`, how would you test that?

Answer (score 4):

In case you follow [rubocops ImplicitExpect](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ImplicitExpect) you might what to use something like this:

```rb
it { is_expected.to validate(%i[home_team], uniqueness: { scope: [:visiting_team, :event_datetime] }) }
```

or

```rb
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime) }
```

*(note that I did not include the custom error message as the original question is very old and my purpose is to help visitors from google rather than the original question author)*

Answer (score 1):

### Using the New "Expect" Lingo

```
let(:line) { build(:line) } # if using factory bot, or you could use fixtures
it {expect(line).to validate_uniqueness_of(:home_team).scoped_to(:visiting_team, :event_datetime)  }
```